# Поиск значения в std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, find

Я создал следующую структуру

```
struct Datas
{
    std::string DataName;
    std::vector<boost::variant<std::string, int, double>> Data;
};

struct Topic
{
    std::string TopicName;
    std::vector<Datas> DataList;
};

struct Group
{
    std::string NodeName;
    std::vector<Topic> TopicList;
};
....
std::vector<Group> test;
```

можно ли искать какие ли данные через std::find?

Comment: Можно. Если допишете сравнение элементов. Или используете `find_if` с соответствующим предикатом.

Comment: @Harry а можно примерчик?

Comment: Какие именно "данные" вы собрались искать? У вас нарисована четырехуровневая иерархическая структура. Что именно и где именно вы собрались искать? Потрудитесь более конкретно сформулировать вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиск в векторе с элементами пользовательского типа возможен - через `find` с помощью оператора равенства, или `find_if` с предоставлением предиката поиска.

Пример - далее.

```
struct Test
{
    string name;
    vector<int> data;
    bool operator==(const Test& t)
    {
        return name == t.name;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<Test> v{ {"a",{1,2,3}}, {"b",{4,5,6}}, {"c",{7,8,9}} };
    // Поиск с использованием оператора равенства (ищем с name=="b")
    if (auto t = find(v.begin(),v.end(),Test{"b",{}}); t != v.end())
    {
        for(auto i: t->data) cout << i << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    // Поиск с использованием предиката - тот, где первый элемент data - 7
    if (auto t = find_if(v.begin(),v.end(),
                         [](const Test& q){ return q.data.size()>0 && q.data[0] == 7; });
        t != v.end())
    {
        for(auto i: t->data) cout << i << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```